# Need clarity on Vidyo Io possibilities

Tags: vidyo

I am just exploring on Vidyo IO platform for enabling video conferencing capabilities on top of one web application. I am just concerned about the below points and trying to get answers for the same.

Can anyone please help me with the details for the below points if you are aware of them?

1. Can we add/remove the participants from the video conference.
2. Can we just have an audio call.
3. Are the conference calls carried in the encrypted mode.
4. Are there any chances like generated API token can be stolen by any hackers and join into the conference call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can we add/remove the participants from the video conference.

Yes. This kind of "moderation" may be achieved via client SDK only as well as via Vidyo backend APIs.

> Can we just have an audio call.

Yes. On your application level you should just not select any local camera device (in Visyo SDK language - .SelectLocalCamera(null)).

> Are the conference calls carried in the encrypted mode.

Yes.

> Are there any chances like generated API token can be stolen by any hackers and join into the conference call.

Token is being generated based on ApplicationID and DeveloperKey that are tied to your personal account. If you don't expose this information, Token will not be compromised.